# How do I set Safari 14 to ensure that Safari prompts me before closing all tabs?

Tags: mac, safari

How do I set a preference to ensure the Safari prompts me before closing all tabs? This version is being used on a Mac so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'Close all Tabs' command. If you accidentally close a window - red dot or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  - you can just restore it from the History menu…

[image]

This says Tab instead of Window if that was what you last closed.
If you completely messed up you can restore all your windows from the previous session.

The Edit menu will let you re-open your recently closed tabs [but only if you are not currently focussed in a text area, when it will undo typing instead].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Quit Confirmation for Safari on MacOS](https://daringfireball.net/2020/01/quit_confirmation_for_safari_on_macos)
treats the case when one hits `⌘Q` in Safari by mistake.
It's easy enough to block `⌘Q` entirely, but an alert is required if you
do want to use it intentionally.

The poster created this AppleScript:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set _window_count to count windows
    set _tab_count to 0

    repeat with _w in every window
        set _tab_count to _tab_count + (count tabs of _w)
    end repeat

    -- Make a string like "1 window containing 3 tabs."
    if _window_count is 1 then
        set _msg to _window_count & " window containing " as string
    else
        set _msg to _window_count & " windows containing " as string
    end if
    if _tab_count is 1 then
        set _msg to _msg & _tab_count & " tab." as string
    else
        set _msg to _msg & _tab_count & " tabs." as string
    end if

    display alert ¬
        "Are you sure you want to quit Safari?" message _msg ¬
        buttons {"Cancel", "Quit"} ¬
        giving up after 60
    if button returned of result is "Quit" then quit
end tell
```

The script will cause this dialog to appear in such a case:

[image]

Using
[FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/),
the poster saved this script as a file in
the "Safari" folder in the "Applications" folder inside his "Scripts" folder,
in FastScript’s preferences, assigned it `⌘Q`.

For more details, see the above-linked post.